# Howler.js: sound doesn't load

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, howler.js

Following [basic example in the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/howler), yet sound doesn't play. I see the `mp3` file in `Network` tab but it's 90KB instead of 5MB so I suppose it doesn't load properly.

I tried different paths: `src: ['@/assets/audios/test.mp3']`, `src: ['../assets/audios/test.mp3']. Nothing works. No console error. Why is it not working?

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <button @click="play">
      PLAY
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Howl, Howler } from 'howler'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      sound: ''
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.sound = new Howl({
      src: ['test.mp3']
    })
  },
  methods: {
    play () {
      this.sound.play()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you running this from a web server?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to load an asset URL for `src`.

1. The asset URL needs to be `require`d so that Webpack resolves the actual URL to the file.
2. Errors are silently ignored, but you can set [`onloaderror`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/howler#onloaderror-function) to handle them.

```js
export default {
  mounted () {
    this.sound = new Howl({
      // 1
      src: [
        require('@/assets/audios/test.mp3')
      ],

      // 2
      onloaderror(id, err) {
        console.warn('failed to load sound file:', { id, err })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if not using asset URLs then what is the package using in the docs? I don't get it. Also using your code I'm getting this error now: `Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:3)
`. Does that mean there's a problem within the mp3 file?

Comment: By "asset URLs", I mean *URLs to resources in `src/assets/` within a Vue CLI scaffolded project.* The package doesn't care where the URL is from, but it must be a valid URL to an existing resource. The URLs given to `Howl` are not automatically transformed, unlike [`<img>.src` in Vue CLI scaffolds](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules), so you'll need to manually `require` them for `Howl`.

Comment: Regarding the parse error: I cannot reproduce that in my local setup. I don't know what that error really means.

Comment: If for some reason you prefer not to use `src/assets/` or `require(URL)`, you could move the mp3s to `public/`, where the URLs don't require transformation.

Comment: I moved the mp3 there and it now works, thanks. But how did you know it would work, the docs say nothing about that part. Also, not sure what to do with your answer since technically I couldn't solve my problem with it.